# rotating the player via a control stick(touchpad) in libGDX

Tags: java, android, math, libgdx

In my libGDX project I want to move a player around the screen with a touchpad. That already works. 
Now I want to rotate the "face" of the player in the direction he is moving.
I have tried it with this little piece of code, but I doesn´t really work

```
double degree;

degree = Math.tan(touchpad.getKnobPercentX()/touchpad.getKnobPercentY());

playerSprite.setRotation((float) degree);
```

I hope u can help me (I have bee searching on Google for about 1 hour before I asked this question, so don't tell me to Google it;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the atan(y/x) function or even better the atan2(y,x) function to get the angle. Check the documentation where you get results in radians and expect inputs in degrees.

tan transforms an angle (in radians) to the tangent value, the slope of the angle.

phi=atan(y/x) is the arc tan, centuries ago written as arg(y/x=tan(phi)). It gives the same result for opposite angles, so you would have to correct for the right quadrant.

phi=atan2(y,x) already performs that correction.